# Azure Graph API - Check if user has full access to an O365 mailbox

Tags: c#, azure, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the [ActiveDirectory GraphClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/) library by Microsoft to access an Azure AD.

**My problem is:**

I'd like to get to known if an **IUser object** has full access to an Office 365 mailbox of another user.

```
void bool HasFullAccess(IActiveDirectoryClient client, IUser currentUser, IUser otherUser)
{
    if (currentUser.ObjectId == otherUser.ObjectId)
    {
        return true;
    }

    //TODO: HOW-TO CHECK IF 'currentUser' HAS FULL ACCESS
    //      TO MAILBOX OF 'otherUser'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really good question, you want to be looking at both the `full_access_as_user` and `full_access_as_app` depending on your scenario. Once you have the access token for the user you should be looking at some of the API calls that are documented in the [Outlook REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api).

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways to check whether a user could access another user's mailbox :

1. EWS Managed API

   If you have permission to access another user's mailbox ,you could get the data via :

   ```
       ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);

       service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user_with_access@example.com", "PASSWORD");

       service.TraceEnabled = true;
       service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;

       service.AutodiscoverUrl("user_with_access@example.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

       var userMailbox = new Mailbox("target_user@example.com");
       var folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, userMailbox);

       var itemView = new ItemView(20);   // page size
       var userItems = service.FindItems(folderId, itemView);

       foreach (var item in userItems)
       {
           // do something with item (nb: it might not be a message)
       }
   ```

   Above code need user's credential .If you don't have permission to access target user's mailbox ,above code will threw an error like " The process failed to get the correct properties" .
2. PowerShell

   By running Get-MailboxPermission cmdlet you can check which user/mailbox has what type of permissions to access other mailboxes in Exchange:

   ```
   Get-Mailbox <Mailbox> | Get-MailboxPermission -User <AD User>
   ```

   You could call powershell to check it in your application .